# css or angular to control view a visibility

Tags: css, angularjs, html

Please consider the code snippet below. I need no footer to show when app starts. During the app's life cycle, some buttons will show and some of their labels will change based on user and/or http.response events.
In regards of showing and hiding the footer, I understand that if no buttons are rendered, the footer will have zero hight.

Is it better to let ng-repeat inject the li (no li same as zero footer hight) or set the footer css property as shown in the code and change it through angular service. I must add that I might like to animate the appearing/dis-appearing of the footer by sliding it from the bottom. Thanks

```css
footer {
    position: fixed;
    /*bottom: -3em;*/
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <ul class="horizontal-style">
        <li><button type="button">NO</button></li>
        <li><button type="button">EXTRA</button></li>
        <li><button type="button">YES</button></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

Comment: Add ng-if condition to <ul>.

Comment: Consider using `ng-hide` for small DOM elements. It also has good hooks into `ngAnimate`. For more info, see [AngularJS ng-hide Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide).